# I'm trying to program a decimal number into binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, decimal, converters

```
import numbers


nummer = int(input("Enter a number:"))
number=()
while nummer == 0: 
    number(nummer)

binary_numbers = format(nummer, "b")

print(binary_numbers)
    
nummer=0
```

output when entering the number 32 is:

`100000`

but I want the rest to be filled with 0 like this:

`00100000`

and i don`t know how

Comment: What do you think will happen if the input is 0? Also, tuples are not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try:

```py
format(nummer, "08b")
```

Comment: Thank you! that helped me straight away

Comment: You are welcome